# Vertical scroll two divs – left down, right up

Tags: scroll, updown

I want a page with two div's next to each other; on scroll down, one scrolls up the other one scrolls down. How can I achieve this? Does this have a name?

See example: https://lifeathome.ikea.com/virtualgreenhouse/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add transform: translateY(-someHeight) to the column that should scroll to the opposite direction on scroll event

Comment: You mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/28h9kwc6/ 

I'm doing something wrong since I just replicated a postion: fixed :p